# multiple instance of tcpip stack in Linux

Tags: linux, tcp, embedded-linux

is it possible to start multiple instance of already available tcpip stack on Linux (Embedded Linux)? If anyone has any information regarding this?

Comment: What do you mean 'start multiple instances'? In general, no - each stack expects to get all packets. In any case, only one could handle starting new connections

Comment: Multiple network adapters?  You can add virtual interfaces such as eth0:0, eth0:1.  This isn't very programming related either.

Comment: @Robert: thanks for the information. actually Linux has tcpip stack already available. If I wrote my own mini tcpip stack (limited edition) and I am using the same network driver interface as Linux. first query, is it possible to keep 2 tcpip stack on Linux? if yes then how to start or load or use other limited tcpip stack and not standard Linux tcpip stack? Please update me with this required information, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can run two complete and independent TCP/IP stacks in Linux. The reason is that the TCP/IP stack is part of the Linux monolithic kernel, and since there's only one kernel running, then there's only one TCP/IP stack running.

Linux provides TUN and TAP interfaces which allow you to perform some operations that are usually done by the TCP/IP stack (this is what VPN software typically uses). This is better thought of as a TCP/IP stack *within* a TCP/IP stack. This might be work for you depending on what your ultimate goal is.

To run two complete and independent TCP/IP stacks at the same time, you'll need to use an operating system other than Linux where the TCP/IP isn't part of the kernel. (A micro-kernel can usually do this e.g., QNX)

Answer (score 1):

You could try network namespaces.
The creation of one includes a creation of a new tcp/ip socket.

See howto:
[https://eos.aristanetworks.com/2011/06/linux-namespaces-at-arista/](https://web.archive.org/web/20120425072529/https://eos.aristanetworks.com/2011/06/linux-namespaces-at-arista/) (archived)